# Full-text with partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table that I want to search in.

Table:

```
user_id: integer
text: text
deleted_at: datetime (nullable)
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "index_notifications_full_text" ON "notifications"
  USING "gist" (to_tsvector('simple'::REGCONFIG, COALESCE(("text")::TEXT, ''::TEXT))) WHERE "deleted_at" IS NULL;
```

I need to implement a full-text search for users (only inside their messages that are not deleted).

How can I implement an index that indexes both user_id and text?

Comment: I don't think coalescing to the empty string accomplishes anything, other than making all your code uglier.  Can't you just let NULLs be NULL?  If you have a lot of NULLs, maybe add `AND text IS NOT NULL` to the WHERE clause of your partial index.

Comment: @jjanes it is recommended to use `coalesce` by docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-controls.html

Comment: I think it is recommending you use `coalesce` if you will `||` the result it into something else.  I don't see a reason to use it standalone in the absence of `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [btree_gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) and/or [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) extensions, you can include user_id directly into a multicolumn FTS index.  You can try it on each type in turn, as it can be hard to predict which one will be better in a given situation.

Alternatively, you could partition the table by user_id using [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE), and then keep the single-column index (although in that case, GIN is likely better than GiST).

If you want more detailed advice, you need to give us more details.  Like how many use_id are there, how many notifications per user_id, and many tokens are there per notification, and an example of a plausible query you hope to support efficiently.

Comment: Looks like btree_gin / btree_gist is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column with the name e.g  document_with_idx with `tsvector` type
on your notifications table,

```
ALTER TABLE notifications ADD COLUMN document_with_idx tsvector;
```

Then update that column value with the vectorized value of user_id and text column.

```
update notifications set document_with_idx = to_tsvector(user_id || ' ' || coalesce(text, ''));
```

Finally, create an index with the name e.g document_idx on that column,

```
CREATE INDEX document_idx
  ON notifications
  USING GIN (document_with_idx);
```

**Now you can do a full-text search on both user_id and text column value using that document_with_idx column.**

Now search like,

```
select user_id, text from notifications
                where document_with_idx @@ to_tsquery('your search string goes here');
```

**See more:** https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-tables.html